# What are the reasons of ICE failure?

Tags: webrtc, turn, ice-protocol

What are the possible reasons of ICE failure ?

I am particularly interested in the case of failure- when all remote candidates are added( with relay candidates ), remote offer/answer SDP set.

Comment: You mean a connection failure between the clients?

Comment: yes. does it matter if the ice candidates are sent out of order ? I mean before the host candidates, the server reflexive or relay candidates are sent ?

Comment: No, that does not matter, there are tons of network reasons for an ICE connection to fail.

Answer (score 8):

One of the reasons of P2P connection failure between two peers is that peer failed in gathering the suitable ice candidates and this is what we called "ICE failure"

So if you mean by ICE failure that the client application not able to get the suitable ice candidates from the ice server so that could happen for many reasons. For Example:

- ICE server down
- P2P connections blocked by Firewall
- Symmetric NAT which does not reuse session address binding. This results some NAT Traversal techniques failing in traverse packets through NAT devices